# triple loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have the following function

```
for z=1:dimensions(2) % maximum of z 
   M = [];
   for t=1:dimensions(4) %% maximum of t
      M = [M test.field_data(x,z,y,t)];
   end 
   t = [time]; 
end
```

I want to create a matrix M that consists of all field_data values for each x y z value (`test.field_data(x,z,y,t)` for a specified t range. 
With this one for-loop, I can get the values for each z number, but how can I extend this so that also the different x (`x=1:dimensions(1)`) values and y (`y=1:dimensions(3)`) values are included? I have difficulties setting up the triple for-loops properly. Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any for loop.

```
test.field_data(1:dimensions(1),z,1:dimensions(3),1:dimensions(4))
```

In your code M is deleted at the beginning of every iteration (`M=[]`)

Comment: I would think you'll also need something like `1:dimensions(4)` instead of `t`.

Comment: Is it possible to get the M matrix as indicated by Daniel R for each t? For example, if t = 1,2,3,4), how can I easily create four matrixes M1, M2, M3 and M4?

Comment: @Justinnl You can create four matrices, but in general I would recommend just adding a time dimension to your matrix. Then you can acess it like `M(z,x,y,t)`, if this is not desirable you can do `M1 = M(z,x,y,1)`

Comment: one additional question :  Ultimately, I want to create a 3D plot with each x,y,z coordinate for each t. Therefore, I will perform a calculation on each datapoint (e.g. result254 = M254(11,12,13,2)/3 ; result 255=M255(11,12,14,2)/3; etc.). What is the best way to refer to each cell in the matrix in order to handle such operations to get a resultmatrix of size max(x) by max(z) by max(y) for each t ?

Comment: I don't know what you really want, but maybe 'M(:,:,:,2)./3' fits your requirements? btw: whenever your variable name contains a number, you should think about using a cell or vector or matrix.

Comment: @DanielR, Thank you very much for your answers, you really helped me out here. The /3 operation was for clarity purposes only; actually I will perform a convolution with the numbers. Due to the size of the x,y,z parameters (144x40x144), I really want to automate each cell operation instead of explicitly state each cell operation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cellfun` to select the relevant `t` interval

```
c = cellfun( @(x) x.filed_data(:,:,:,t_intrvl), test, 'UniformOutput', false );
```

`cat` the cells into a single array `M`

```
M = cat( 4, c{:} ); % cat along fourth dim
```

You can `reshape` `M` anyway you please now.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Actually, I think that the answer without the concatenate part would work perfectly. Depending on the number of t_intrvl a corresponding amount of Matrices M will be created, right? Is it possible to store each Matrix individually ( e.g. M1, M2, M3, etc. )?

Comment: @Justinnl you can partition `M` into several cell elements using `mat2cell`.